# how to convert all video format files into (audio) mp3 files in ruby

Tags: ruby

how to convert all video format files into (audio) mp3 files in ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this one's a little tricky. There's not really a -great- way to this with ruby, but here goes.

The best option I can think of is to wrap an external call to call ffmpeg to do the conversion. Something like this:

```
source_video = params[:video_file]
%x[ffmpeg -i #{source_video} -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192 -f mp3 sound.mp3]
```

Answer (score 1):

use ffmpeg for this purpose. 
http://ffmpeg.org/